# Where does `time` output its result?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, time

I'm on Ubuntu.

Running `time` seems to output its result to something other than `STDOUT` or `STDERR`. Here's why I think so:

```
[siminm@amide ~]$ time echo hi
hi

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
[siminm@amide ~]$ time echo hi >/dev/null 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
[siminm@amide ~]$ time echo hi 2>/dev/null 
hi

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
[siminm@amide ~]$ time echo hi 2>&1 >/dev/null 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
[siminm@amide ~]$ time echo hi &>/dev/null 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

**HOWEVER**

```
[siminm@amide ~]$ /usr/bin/time echo hi 2>/dev/null 
hi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell, which is probably bash, provides a builtin command `time`. There is also a separate program called `time` in `/usr/bin/`, which is in your `$PATH`. The behavior of the two is different. If you want consistency across all configurations, you should use the program `/usr/bin/time` instead of the bash builtin `time`.

Comment: When I run `which time` it returns `/usr/bin/time`

Comment: @Mikhail, what does `type -a time` tell you?

Comment: @glenn, `time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time` -- this is rather self explanatory now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"time" builtin output goes to what stderr points to **before** redirections do happen.

Any non builtin command like /usr/bin/time cannot override the redirection as they happen before it is launched so its output goes to stderr.

Answer (score 1):

You are always only redirecting the output of your command. Since time writes to stderr try the following:

```
(time ls >> /stdout/output/of/ls 2>> /stderr/output/of/ls) 2>> /output/of/time
```

Comment: This is great! I had no idea you can wrap functions in parenthesis like that